Performance Considerations for Concurrent non-blocking scatter operations in MPI
I have a problem in which I have several subcommunicators, which may consist of overlapping ranks from the global 'world' communicator. From each subcommunicator's root process I wish to issue a scatter operation.
My question, being unfamiliar with MPI internals is, if I issue non-blocking scatters from each subcommunicator root to what extent does MPI handle communication between overlapping communicators for me as a programmer?
For example if rank 0 is scattering to ranks [1,2,3,4,10], and rank 10 is scattering to ranks [0,1,2,11,12,13], simultaneously via a non-blocking scatter. Are these handled sequentially by MPI schedulers? I.e. wait for the scattering from rank 0 to resolve, and proceed to that of rank 10?
I'd appreciate if someone could link a technical description of how these are handled in common MPI implementations.
best wishes,
S

First, you should understand the difference between scatter and broadcast. Then you should understand that root is not a property of the communicator, but rather a decision for each individual collective communication call. All collective communication functions must be executed by all processes that are member of the communicator with consistent values. Since you use non-blocking communication, the ordering in which the processes start their collective calls does not matter as long as you make sure to start all communication calls before waiting for their completion.

If you use the default coll/libnbc component of Open MPI, the non blocking collectives are progressed concurrently. I cannot speak for other components nor implementations. You'd rather write to figure this out.

Apologies if you know this, but it's unclear from the question: it's important to remember that in MPI scatter is collective operation. This means that all processes in the communicator must call the same operation with compatible arguments (e.g. for MPI_Scatter, they must all have the same root process).
For non-blocking collectives, these are isolated per communicator and requests on different communicators should not interfere with each other, unless you cause a deadlock by waiting on them in the wrong order (an MPI_Waitall should be correct). So I'd say MPI will handle all the communication for you.
Your example is a little confusing to me as recall that each communicator numbers its processes independently and that a collective acts across all processes in the communicator.

For example if rank 0 is scattering to ranks [1,2,3,4,10], and rank 10 is scattering to ranks [0,1,2,11,12,13], simultaneously via a non-blocking scatter. Are these handled sequentially by MPI schedulers?

Let's assume your numbers are process ranks in MPI_COMM_WORLD, and further that comm1 has 6 processes with world ranks [0,1,2,3,4,10] (local ranks 0...5 inclusive) and comm2 has 7 processes with world ranks [0,1,2,10,11,12,13] (local ranks 0...6 inclusive). Let's assume we send 2 integers from root to each process in both cases.
If you begin like this:
MPI_Request reqs[2];
if (onComm1)
  MPI_Iscatter(sendbuf1, 2, MPI_INT, recvbuf1, 2, MPI_INT, 0, comm1, reqs);
else
  reqs[0] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

if (onComm2)
  // Not the root rank is 3 as that's world-rank 10 has that rank in comm2
  MPI_Iscatter(sendbuf2, 2, MPI_INT, recvbuf2, 2, MPI_INT, 3, comm2, reqs + 1);
else
  reqs[1] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

Then wait with MPI_Waitall(2, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE). A conforming MPI implementation must make it work, even under the weak progress guarantee. Note that for a given communicator, nonblocking collectives must be ordered, but here you have separate communicators so you do not have that constraint.
The MPI standard doesn't specify how this is to happen, but both Open MPI and MPICH create a "schedule" when a nonblocking collective is started: this is an ordered list of operations that that process needs to do to implement the NBC (send, receive, copy, apply operation, wait, etc..)
For scatter in Open MPI's default, it's very simple (https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/39a8583a7f7aae633d75f5a6644ef2517e517010/ompi/mca/coll/libnbc/nbc_iscatter.c#L87) Non-root processes do a non-blocking receive into their buffer. Root process does MPI_Comm_size-1 sends to the other processes and copies (if not in place) to its own buffer.
MPICH's default is a bit more sophisticated: it uses a binomial tree algorithm.
https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/dfad000383bd21a2bf39005c5f12b316ec37a759/src/mpi/coll/iscatter/iscatter_intra_sched_binomial.c#L66
In both cases the schedule is then handed off to the MPI progress engine to get on with. This might be a separate progress thread or the library could just do a bit every time your application calls any MPI function. Both MPI implementations have extension mechanisms so implementation of the NBCs can be changed e.g. to take advantage of any fancy NIC the system has.

Hi, thanks for this. I understand that all processes in a communicator must call a particular collective. However, I have multiple (physical nodes) each of which have multiple MPI communicators associated with them. I think my example is a little confusing as I don't have the correct terminology. Global rank 10 in my example corresponds to a physical node that is involved in two collective communications in two subcommunicators containing an overlap (in physical nodes).

In my real code I'm looping over all world ranks, finding out which subcommunicators are involved for a communication involving this world rank, and issuing the appropriate scatter and receive calls. As (world rank) 10 is involved in two overlapping subcommunicators in my example, I was wondering if the first scatter would have to complete before the second one can be issued from this physical node, and whether MPI could handle this concurrently or my loop over world ranks is serialised. If that makes sense?

Your operations would only be ordered if you use blocking scatter. With non-blocking scatter as sketched in the code above, the scatters can complete in any order. You have the guarantee that the non-root processes will only complete the scatter after the root process started the communication. Regarding performance, you might observe that for some implementations only provide progress when all your processes are in the MPI_Wait call. For mpich you might get better performance using MPICH_ASYNC_PROGRESS=1

MPI as standardised mostly doesn't concern itself with nodes, only processes (main exception being one-sided operations). But if you have done MPI_Iscatter on separate communicators then there is no constraint on the ordering of completion. (Within a communicator, non blocking collectives are ordered.) Each communicator holds an independent communication context

I just noticed you wrote "issuing the appropriate scatter and receive calls" - for a collective scatter (i.e. MPI_Scatter/MPI_Iscatter) there is no "receive" call, the MPI library takes care of all data movement on your behalf. Are you in fact doing a scatter yourself by making multiple sends from the root and a receive from the other processes?
